# I need the way to aggregate based on column value using MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am learning Charts in Laravel, i need to draw Line graph for daily Student Attendance for those students come late or on time. I tried to write MYSQL query but it doesn't work

I tried subquery on same table to get data for daily students and i also need 7 dates only not full date, like date is stored in db as 09/08/2019 but i need it as 08 as date.

```
SELECT Date, COUNT(*) AS TimeStudent
   FROM attendance WHERE `Attendance`='OnTime' AND (SELECT COUNT(*) AS 
   LateStudent FROM attendance 
   WHERE `Attendance`='Late'
   GROUP BY `Date`
   ORDER BY LateStudent DESC) 
   GROUP BY `Date`
   ORDER BY TimeStudent DESC
```

but i got

> [Err] 1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

, because i can't use to fetch Date again in subquery while use it after where clause. Any one help me plz.

Comment: Show us some sample data along with expected output. [https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @paul-spiegel would you please write the answer if you know it?

Comment: @jitendra-yadav what type of sample data do you need? should i share snap shot of table? from which i need to fetch data

Comment: Yup, that would be good and include expected output too.

Comment: You can use `date_format` for the same also based on expected output, we can suggest you to modify query to get data in simpler and correct way.

Comment: would you write a sample query which will show those students list who were late or attended class on time?

Comment: I provided you a sample query but if you show me what should be output I can help you more. Like you want list of students who are `late` and `on time` for a particular date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to aggregate based on column value.

This query will give you count of `on time` and `late` student for a particular date.

```
SELECT 
    `Date`,
    DATE_FORMAT(`Date`, '%d') AS Month_Date,  -- You can modify it as per your requirement
    SUM(IF(`Attendance` = 'OnTime', 1, 0)) AS OnTime_Count,
    SUM(IF(`Attendance` = 'Late', 1, 0)) AS Late_Count
FROM attendance
WHERE `Date` >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY
GROUP BY `Date`;
```

Comment: Thanks actually its the correct query for which i was trying. thanks @jitendra-yadav

Comment: Okay do update your question, so everyone can understand what you're looking for.

Comment: would you help me to know the how to change the same query for weekly and monthly attendance as it was for daily attendance. Thanks in advance @jitendra-yadav

Comment: Just do `GROUP BY MONTH(date)` for month and same for week as we have week function in mysql. Make sure to update the where clause to include the dates which you want to include in calculation.